# Flat buttons, listview android

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a hard time pointing out what UI elements are used here? Is it buttons or listviews?

[image]

Comment: Think this is a gridView with buttons, but you can have a look at it with hierachyviewer

Comment: it could be anything and similar result can be achieved using many methods. but the simplest would be as @A.S. said gridview with buttons

Comment: Its so few items, no reason to bother with a view that requires an adapter (listview/gridview).

Comment: Buttons / ImageButtons or eve TextViews in a GridView / GridLayout or a TableLayout. Or simply Buttons (or ...) in a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Ok but i think its just normal buttons with special style?

Answer (score 0):

This view is not seems as a list view. They are either Buttons or ImageButtons fitted in some layout.

Comment: I'm so thinking, this might be buttons with some style. I really like it, it looks so mature

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this in a ListView, you are gonna have a hard time. The best would be to make it in a GridLayout, if you are not that confident in working with that then the easiest solution would be a `LinearLayout` in the root with vertical orientation, and then add a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation where the childs have `weight="1"

Something like this (Just for the first two buttons):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:onClick="onChildOneClick">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:background="android:color/green" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onChildTwoClick" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside your framelayout you can put a `ImageView` + `TextView` to make it look like the sketch

Comment: Those 2 top buttons are not exapandable , the layout is like this when opened

Comment: If the layout is like this (static) and wont change, then you can use my sample and write it all in XML?

Comment: Did you try put some textviews inside the framelayouts to test? I will edit my answer to show example